# rpm --upgrade of the same package gives file conflicts

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I have installed my custom package containing a bunch of files.

Running `rpm --upgrade` a second time gives a lot of errors:

`File ABC from install of mypackage-1.0-0.i386 conflicts with file from package mypackage-1.0-0.i386`

RPM exits with error code 5.

But its the same package with same version number!  Should it not say "already installed" or something?  What do I need to do to the spec file or rpm upgrade command to avoid this problem?

Running `rpm --upgrade --replacefiles` says "package *mypackage-1.0-0.i386* already installed", with exit code 5

(I don't really want to replace the files if they haven't changed...

[image: A few of the error messages]

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. The easiest is to increase the version and/or release when you build a new package so that the `rpm -U` (upgrade) command will work normally. If you don't want to do that, you can use `rpm -U --replacefiles --replacepkgs` to effectively reinstall the package. A third option is to remove the package before installing the "new" one.

In all of these cases, all files that are part of the regular paylod (i.e. are not marked as `noreplace` config files) will be replaced with the newer versions. That's just how RPM works. If you want to go down the path of only updating things that have changed, you'll need to look into generating DRPM packages (Delta RPM), which do contain only differences from a previous version. That will require you to increment your version and/or release numbers when you rebuild. I've never done delta RPM packages, so I can't offer any advice on them.